# Create side menu in bootstrap?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I found several topic on the net that show how to build a side collapsible menu, but all of this require a lot of code, I need only to show or hide a specific div, in particular I've this structure:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <div class="well">
            <span><b>Resources</b></span>
            <form class="form-inline">
                <input type="text" placeholder="type text here"
                       class="form-control" id="resource_filter" />
                <button class="clear btn btn-default btn-sm" type="button"
                        title="clean">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-repeat"></span>
                </button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <div id="calendar" class="well"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want show or hide the div with `col-md-2` class, so the last div (col-md-10) can have the max width dimension. How can I do this simple?

Comment: what is the issue now?

Comment: @RajshekarReddy He's asking how to do.

Comment: here are some useful snippets http://bootsnipp.com/search?q=side+bar

Comment: Use the Bootstrap collapse component to toggle the sidebar.

Comment: @ZimSystem could you link this component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you say you want something like this? Please view it in full screen.

1. Toggle the sidebar with the `hidden` class.
2. Toggle the main bar with `col-XX-12` or `col-XX-10` class.

**Snippet**

```js
$(function () {
  $("#btnShoHide").click(function () {
    $(".hideable-sidebar").toggleClass("hidden");
    $(".expandable-main").toggleClass("col-xs-10 col-xs-12");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-2 hideable-sidebar">
      <div class="well">
        <span><b>Resources</b></span>
        <form class="form-inline">
          <input type="text" placeholder="type text here"
                 class="form-control" id="resource_filter" />
          <button class="clear btn btn-default btn-sm" type="button"
                  title="clean">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-repeat"></span>
          </button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-10 expandable-main">
      <div id="calendar" class="well">
        <input type="button" class="btn btn-default" value="Show or Hide" id="btnShoHide" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the example, is possible put the button on the div itself? Also I want ask if is possible hide the menu automatically when a minimum resolution is fired, thanks for the fast example :)

Comment: @AgainMe yes, it is possible. You can try playing with the JS and classes.

Comment: @AgainMe Tell me what exactly you are looking for, so that I can give you a suggestion. Put the `<input type="button" />` wherever you wanna put.

Comment: something like this: http://www.jasny.net/bootstrap/examples/navmenu-push/ is possible achieve the same target with your code? Thanks

Comment: @AgainMe Push is definitely possible in an easy way. BTW, you have that code, why not use the same one?

Comment: I don't understand how can I get jasny plugin working

Comment: @AgainMe I don't understand what you are telling, sorry?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130801/discussion-between-againme-and-praveen-kumar).